# WPF Grid Rows and ResizeGrip do not anchor correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

once again after hours of struggle with WPF I need your awesome help.

I have read many different StackOverflows, nonetheless, I cannot seem to get my current situation working and I don't understand why. I have chosen to use a Grid in contrast to a DockPanel and I would like to keep it that way as well. According to what I have read the row definitions are ok, the second row of the template grid should automatically stretch. Unfortunately it does not, as it seems that the last row of the grid does not move away.

This is how my window looks at the moment:
[image]

As you can see is the blue row not at the bottom of the window. In fact, the window should not be that long in the first place.

This is the code snippet of my Generic.xaml file that is relevant to the problem.
The way it works is, that I have a Skin with a custom control group:

```
<!-- Window START-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Background="Red" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid x:Name="WindowRoot" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Blue" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- HEADER START-->
            <Frame x:Name="header_background" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Background="#ddd" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="#c9c9c9"/>
            <Image x:Name="LogoICon" Source="/MTApp;component/Resources/Icon.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 8"/>                        
            <Label x:Name="windowTitle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#393939" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" FontSize="12"/>
            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/> 
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="minimizeBtn" Content="0" FontFamily="Marlett" Foreground="#393939" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3 0 0 0" Click="minimizeBtn_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="maximizeBtn" Content="2" FontFamily="Marlett" Foreground="#393939" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3 0 0 0" Click="maximizeBtn_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="quitBtn"     Content="r" FontFamily="Marlett" Foreground="#393939" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="3 0 0 0" Click="quitBtn_Click"/>
            </Grid>

            <!-- HEADER END-->
            <!-- CONTENT START-->
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1"  Height="Auto"/>
            <!-- CONTENT END-->

            <!-- FOOTER START-->
            <Border x:Name="footer_background" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="2" Height="25">
                <ResizeGrip />
            </Border>

            <!-- FOOTER END-->
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
<!-- Window END-->

<Style x:Key="LightSkin_0_1" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplate}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And my MainWindow.xaml is:

```
<Window x:Class="UHashIt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UHashIt"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window title"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    MinHeight="275"
    MinWidth="700"
    Width="700" 
    Style="{DynamicResource LightSkin_0_1}">
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="5" Background="#f2f2f2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <DockPanel >
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="Add File" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Export.." />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Help">
                    <MenuItem Header="Online Documentation" />
                    <MenuItem Header="About"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
    <!-- Menu End -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Style="{DynamicResource headline4}" Content="File 1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource NormalTextBox}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource CommonButton}" Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Style="{DynamicResource headline5}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <Label Style="{DynamicResource headline4}" Content="File 2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Style="{DynamicResource NormalTextBox}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{DynamicResource CommonButton}" Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Style="{DynamicResource headline5}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>


        <!-- Hash Button and Selection -->
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="30">
            <ComboBoxItem>
                Please Choose Your Algorithm
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Style="{DynamicResource ActionBtn}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <!-- End-->

    </Grid>
    <!-- Content End-->
</Grid>
```

I cannot explain myself why the "blue bar" is not attached to the bottom. Despite the fact, that the window is so big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change this:

```
 <Grid x:Name="WindowRoot" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Blue" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
```

to this:

```
     <Grid x:Name="WindowRoot" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
```